# selection to show different div for every item

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a specific div appear or not based on what I select in the listbox. but I don't understand where I'm wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type='text/css'>
        .multiselectUsers {
            width: 200px;
            display: none;
        }
        .multiselectAnagrafica {
            width: 200px;
            display: none;
        }
        .multiselectForm {
            width: 200px;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='post'>
        <select id='tabella' style='display:inline-block' onchange='Cusers();'>
              <option value='users'>users</option>
              <option value='anagrafica'>anagrafica</option>
              <option value='form'>form</option>
        </select>
        <p style='display:inline-block'>output: </p>
        <div class='multiselectUsers'>
            <!--something-->
        </div>
        <div class='multiselectAnagrafica'>
            <!--something-->
        </div>
        <div class='multiselectForm'>
            <!--something-->
        </div>      
    </form>
</body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        function Cusers(){  
            var users = 'users';
            var anagrafica = 'anagrafica';
            var form = 'form';
            var e = document.getElementById('tabella');
            var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            if (val == users) {
                document.getElementById('multiselectUsers').style.display = 'inline-block';
                document.getElementById('multiselectAnagrafica').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('multiselectForm').style.display = 'none';              
            } else if (val == anagrafica) {
                document.getElementById('multiselectUsers').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('multiselectAnagrafica').style.display = 'inline-block';
                document.getElementById('multiselectForm').style.display = 'none';  
            } else if (val == form){
                document.getElementById('multiselectUsers').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('multiselectAnagrafica').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('multiselectForm').style.display = 'inline-block';  
            }
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

adding `alert (val);` inside each if, I see that changing the selection, the alert appears with the correct value, so I assume that the problem is related to how I tell him to change the style.display, but I do not understand what is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use `getElementById`, but you don't have any tag with corresponding ID (only CSS classnames). You should replace your `class` attributes in div tags with `id` (and also update the CSS, replacing `.` by `#`.